# SetThreadLocale Function

Tags: c++, windows-xp

SetThreadLocale() function is not working with operating system as Windows XP. So if anyone can help on this. I want to set language as german but that API is not working. If anyone have solution with other API then please tell me.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must download the German language pack first or else Windows will just use the OS default localization on your system.

Download location:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/language-packs#lptabs=xp

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't have any problem with setting my operating system language as German or some different language. My problem is my application is not getting translated to different language when I change language from control panel. It is happening because that SetThreadLocale() is not working for XP as it works fine for vista or later OS. So I need solution for that thing. Or if there is any other API which will change the language of application working on XP. It will help me. Thank you.

Comment: @Manya5384 Setting your operating system to German usually just changes your keyboard layout, numbers, and dates. Does all the languages all the texts in Windows also change to German? If it don't then you don't have a German language pack installed. Windows only come with one OS language; so unless you have'nt installed a German language pack it's not there, just being able to change to a German keyboard layout _does not_ imply having the German language pack installed. A simple test is calling `std::setlocale(LC_ALL,"de_DE");` and then `std::cout<<GetSystemErrorString(1);` expecting German.

Comment: Means you are saying that if my default OS language is German then my application will be in german. I will try this option and will let you know about the results. Thank you very much.